# How to use instance profile credentials available on running ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create tags from within the running ec2 instance, for that I need credentials and I wanted to use the credentials available at `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/identity-credentials/ec2/security-credentials/ec2-instance`. I set access key, secret key and session token as env variables from the above url . Now I tried

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-instanceid --tags Key=Test,Value=Testing --region us-east-1
```

its giving me the following error

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the CreateTags
>   operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded
>   authorization failure message

Comment: **Side-note:** There is no need to add the metadata credentials to environment variables. Any program running on that instance that uses an AWS SDK (including the AWS CLI) will be able to automatically extract the credentials from the metadata. Simply run your command without having to worry about them.

Comment: John - when I directly try to run the create-tags command without setting credentials in env `aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-instanceid --tags Key=Test,Value=Testing --region us-east-1` it says `Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"`

Comment: That would indicate that an IAM role has not been assigned to the EC2 instance. This is, of course, quite strange if you are then able to extract the credentials from the metadata. Something is going strange on that instance.

Comment: It looks like I cannot do anything from instance because while creating instance IAM role was set to NONE. Also I dont have enough permissions to add roles to instances

Comment: An alternative to using an IAM Role is to take credentials from an IAM User. You _might_ have sufficient permission to go to the IAM management console and examine your own IAM User record. Under the **Security Credentials**, you could **Create access key**. The resulting Access Key and Secret Key can be used to make requests as your IAM User, so they will have the same permissions as you have. If you can't create the key, then again it is a matter of speaking with your Administrator to gain appropriate access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these credentials by invoking aws cli without any parameters related to credentials, it will try to pick up the creds from the instance profile. Your problem is not that you do not have the credentials but that you do not have permission to invoke CreateTags operation. As the error message says it is an authorization problem not an authentication one. You need to change the instance profile policy and include the capability to change instance tags.

More here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html

Comment: I cannot perform any of the steps it says `Accessdenied not authorized to perform iam CreateRole`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your role allows you to create, list, delete tags on EC2 or if you require a custom policy attached with this role to allow these actions.

In summary, you should have:

```
  {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:CreateTags",
    "ec2:DeleteTags"
  ]
  }
```

Comment: I cannot add these through console. It says I dont have permissions.

Comment: You can also do this via AWS CLI if you can access

Comment: Where to add these? I'm new to AWS CLI

Comment: You should create a new policy that allows you to create and update tags on EC2. Here's an example - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/put-role-policy.html

Comment: @DevOpsGuY if you don't have permission in the console, you won't have permission via the CLI.

Comment: You should ask your Administrator to modify the permissions in the IAM Role that is associated with the Amazon EC2 instance, to include permission to create tags.

Comment: Via console I can add/delete instance tags or create/delete any instance itself. But I'm not able to do it from running ec2 instance.

Comment: @DevOpsGuY That would be because the IAM Role that is assigned to the instance has different permissions than those assigned to you as an IAM User who has logged into the console.